# Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return renderReCaptcha() }" on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, magento2.4.3, recaptcha

On the checkout page I am getting the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return renderReCaptcha() }"`. I searched for the `renderReCaptcha()` function and found it in `\vendor\magento\module-re-captcha-frontend-ui\view\frontend\web\template\reCaptcha.html` the template looks fine to me though:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 -->

<div data-bind="{
    attr: {
        'id': getReCaptchaId() + '-wrapper'
    },
    'afterRender': renderReCaptcha()
}">
    <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
    <!-- ko if: (!getIsInvisibleRecaptcha()) -->
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value=""
                   class="required-captcha checkbox"
                   name="recaptcha-validate-"
                   data-validate="{required:true}"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

[image: afterRender: function(){return renderReCaptcha() }]

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Msquare No, they wanted to fix it on version 2.4.3-p1 - well it's still there. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33741 for more details. At least it's only an ugly error message but not stopping the store from working...

Comment: @Msquare - the link you have shared is not working. Can you let me know how can I resolve this issue

Comment: @NileshDubey please check it

Answer (score 3):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requiejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha' : {
                'VendorName_ModuleName/js/reCaptcha-mixin' : true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**reCaptcha-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/registry',
    'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptchaScriptLoader',
    'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/nonInlineReCaptchaRenderer'
], function (Component, $, ko, _, registry, reCaptchaLoader, nonInlineReCaptchaRenderer) {
    'use strict';

    return function(Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            initCaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }
                this._super();
            },
            
            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }
                return this.settings.invisible;
            }
        });   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is core Magento bug.

Please see here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33741
The fix is here: https://github.com/magento/security-package/pull/302/files